# Delete each file older than X days in Y folder

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I wrote this but it doesn't work.
In `giorni` I put the maximum days of stay in the SD and`file_dir` is the default location where the files are analyzed.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

file_dir = "/home/pi/" #location 
giorni = 2 #n max of days

giorni_pass = datetime.now() - timedelta(giorni)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_dir):
    for file in files:
        filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file))
        if filetime > giorni_pass:
            os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with:

```
for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(file_dir, file)
        filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(path))
        if filetime > giorni_pass:
            os.remove(path)
```

Because "Filenames" contains a list of files whose path name is relative to "file_dir" and to make operations on those files should first get the absolute path, using `path = os.path.join(file_dir, file)`